# Creating page when form submitted

Tags: drupal

I have created a module for drupal. 
I has 3 files: .install, .info , .module

In .install file I have written the code so that the table creates automatically.

In .module file I have lots of forms so I don't want to paste it here. So user inputs it's name, etc. I click submit and it is saved into my table in the database. Now I have function `repman_submissions()` which i use to display data into a table.

My question is this how can I when i click submit (when user inputs data) create a page that shows the data that is inputed and that you can later go to(lets say test.com/user).

It's like when you use add content it takes the title that you write and turnes in into a link ( a page ).
My problem is I don't know how to do that I have the data in database and I can show it like a table but I don't have a page for the specific data like lets say for a user name to be the link.

Comment: What's the drupal version?!

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and call the page callback function to display your data.

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/def'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'repman_submissions',
    );
    return $items;
  }

  function repman_submissions()($ghi = 0, $jkl = '') {
    // code to display your data
  }
```

Comment: Yeah i have that all ready. I have a menu and a link to my table of inputed content from the form. But i want let's say the subject to be the link. Lets say that the subject is green apple i want to link to be http://example.com/green_apple. So every time you inputed data into a form it will create a site whit the link that is taken from the subject.

Comment: You can use [path_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/path_save/7) function to generate path alias in D7, For D6 use  [path_set_alias](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21path%21path.module/function/path_set_alias/6).